# Second column occupying the rows 1 and 2

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I'm using the code below, is it possible for the material UI for column 2 to occupy both rows 1 and 2?

```
import { Grid, Paper } from "@mui/material";

const DataGrid = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ flexGrow: 1, marginTop: "16px" }}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Paper
                style={{ padding: "16px", textAlign: "center", color: "#000" }}
              >
                Row 1 Column 1a
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Paper
                style={{ padding: "16px", textAlign: "center", color: "#000" }}
              >
                Row 1 Column 1b
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper
            style={{ padding: "16px", textAlign: "center", color: "#000" }}
          >
            Column 2
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container spacing={3} pt={1}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper
            style={{ padding: "16px", textAlign: "center", color: "#000" }}
          >
            Row 2, Column 1
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataGrid;
```

So instead of this

[image]

It should be something like this

[image]

Comment: Look at here: https://mui.com/system/grid/#grid-auto-flow